# Does the equation $2^n \equiv r \bmod n$ have solution?

Tags: diophantine-equations, congruences, pseudoprimes

Given an integer $r$, is there a way to determine if there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $2^n \equiv r \bmod n$? What if the condition $0 \leq r < n$ is required?

I came up with this question thinking about [Fermat pseudo-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) in base $2$. Of course one can generalize looking at the equation $a^n \equiv r \bmod n$, for a fixed integer $a > 1$, but I think that the case $a = 2$ is already interesting.

Thank you in advance for any idea.

**EDIT:** It is conjectured that for any integer $r > 1$ there is a solution $n$ (see Robert Israel's answer). Is there some heuristic reason of why it should be so?

Answer (score 1):

It is conjectured that the answer is yes for every nonnegative integer $r$ except $1$. See OEIS sequences [A015910](https://oeis.org/A015910) and [A036236](https://oeis.org/A036236) and references there.

Comment: Thanks Robert Israel. I checked OEIS for $(2^n \bmod n)$, $n=1,\ldots,1000$, but after sorting its terms in increasing order! So I didn't find anything... Anyway, before check your answer I'll wait to see if somebody has a reason why the conjecture should be true.